# Eclipse Epsilon EMF Eugenia not appearing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

I am new on eclipse, trying to learn how to use the environment. I created my Plug in project with a emf file inside. However, when trying to "Right click, Eugenia, Generate GMF editor", the Eugenia option doesn't show at all in the menu.

[Right clicking my .emf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtgOZ.png)

First, I checked for updates, tried uninstalling/installing the emfatic package at https://download.eclipse.org/emfatic/update/.
I tried installing Epsilon 2.2, 2.3, 2.4 with jdk 14.0.2, 15.0.2, 17 and 21.
None changed anything so I am guessing the problem is elsewhere but I can't see where.
I am on Windows 11.
Please

Answer (score 1):

Eugenia has been retired and is no longer available in Epsilon's interim update site. Could you please double-check that you haven't installed Epsilon from its interim site?

Comment: I first installed Epsilon using the eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe file. And to be sure I reinstalled it with this launcher [link](https://eclipse.dev/epsilon/download/) (eclipse-inst-win64.exe) but the option Eugenia still doesn't appear.